# how do I access or sort the files of a directory in another order that the alphabetical order?

Tags: linux, bash

I run the following commands in linux on a pdf file to convert its pages to image files. However, it runs twice over the pdf file

```
pdftoppm  -H 700  -f 30 -l 40 -png rl.pdf top
pdftoppm -y 700  -f 30 -l 40 -png rl.pdf bottom
```

output would be (the list of output files):

```
bottom-001.png
bottom-002.png
top-001.png
top-002.png
```

However, I want to access and process them in the following order (for `ffmpeg`):

```
top-001.png
bottom-001.png
top-002.png
bottom-002.png
```

To reach this goal you may suggest another way for naming the output files or run another script on the output files to sort them out.

Comment: I think you better reformulate your question as: "how do I access the files of a directory in another order that the alphabetical order?"

Comment: @PierreFrançois Okay I did, however I have another option which is generating them in my desired order, just don't know how

Answer (score 2):

```
sort -n -t- -s -k2
```

Sort numerically using `-` as separator on the second field. Stable sort so that top is on top.

Alternatively sort the first field in reverse:

```
sort -t- -k2n -k1r
```

For example the following command:

```
echo 'bottom-001.png
bottom-002.png
top-001.png
top-002.png' | sort -t- -k2n -k1r
```

outputs:

```
top-001.png
bottom-001.png
top-002.png
bottom-002.png
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't get, where and when I should use them? just typing them in bash has no result, it just waits and nothing happens

Comment: On the output you presented. I never used `pdftoppm`. If the `pdftoppm` process outputs the filenames (ie. prints the filenames on it's standard output) you could `{ pdftoppm ...; pdftoppm ...;} | sort ...`. If by "output" you mean that files are created, not filenames are printed, you could first `find` the files first and then sort. Like `find ... | sort ...`.

Comment: The output is just the list of files in the directory!

Comment: They are sorted by the bash alphabetically. So, I must rename them or produce them so that to be in my desired order.

Comment: I created filenames with above names and wrote `echo *.png | sort -t- -k2n -k1r`, but it had no effect (however your example works), what's the problem?

Comment: `echo *.png` produces a single line with four filenames. You need the four filenames each on their own line, so use `printf '%s\n' *.png`. (Or you can use  `ls *.png` or `ls|grep 'png$'` or a `find` command. But `printf` is more efficient, since it's a built-in.)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution in this case is adding a suffix (in alphabetical order) to the output files of each command and move them to a new directory:

```
pdftoppm  -H 450  -f 30 -l 40 -png rl.pdf page
for file in *.png; do
     mv "$file" "out/${file%.png}_a.png"
done

pdftoppm  -y 700 -f 30 -l 40 -png rl.pdf page
for file in *.png; do
     mv "$file" "out/${file%.png}_b.png"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Variants of sorting with `ls` command

```
$ ls --help
...
  -r, --reverse              reverse order while sorting
  -S                         sort by file size, largest first
      --sort=WORD            sort by WORD instead of name: none (-U), size (-S),
                               time (-t), version (-v), extension (-X)
  -t                         sort by modification time, newest first
  -u                         with -lt: sort by, and show, access time;
                               with -l: show access time and sort by name;
                               otherwise: sort by access time, newest first
  -U                         do not sort; list entries in directory order
  -v                         natural sort of (version) numbers within text
  -X                         sort alphabetically by entry extension
```